# Google sheets API - Import data only when sheet changed (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, import, google-sheets-api

with the following script I retrieve data from a google sheet:

```
// 1. Retrieve the named range list.
    const base = `https:\/\/sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${ID}`;
    const res1 = await fetch(`${base}?key=${API_KEY}&fields=namedRanges(name)`);
    const { namedRanges } = await res1.json();
    console.log(namedRanges);

    // 2. Retrieve values from named ranges.
    const ranges = namedRanges.map(({ name }) => `ranges=${encodeURIComponent(name)}`).join("&");
    const res2 = await fetch(`${base}/values:batchGet?key=${API_KEY}&${ranges}`);
    const { valueRanges } = await res2.json();

    // 3. Create an output object.
    const res = valueRanges.reduce((o, { values }, i) => (o[namedRanges[i].name] = values, o), {});
    console.log(res);
```

Since the data in the sheet could change, I am running the script every second with setinterval() to update the data retrieved regularly.

Is there a way to instead only execute the script, when the data in the Google sheet  changed?

Does Google Sheets offer some sort of webhook or other API to notify you when something changes on the sheet?

Answer (score 0):

I review the documentation of Google and other Stackoverflow post, and the only option I can think up is to create an if with the Drive API with `Revisions: list`. If the latest update is different from the one store in the previews run, then run your script, else to do nothing.

That way, the only API that requests that will be constantly running will be the [revision list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/revisions/list).

The API limits for Google Drive are 100 queries per second, so running that request every second will use 1% of the allowed quota. You can read more information about the quota limits, in [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/limits).

Or you can request a missing feature to Google [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/support#missing_features).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not exactly what I am looking for. I don't want an email notification but rather a way for the above script to only trigger when the sheet data was changed so that I can limit the number of updates required.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I will add an update with more information.